# Yii - When is MySQL CREATE VIEW invoked?

Tags: mysql, yii, view

I've been handed a Yii app to maintain and extend and I'm in the familiarizing process, mostly with Yii as I haven't used it before.

The app uses MySQL views at a pretty large extent and many models are based on them rather than tables.

What I cant figure out is, where/when does Yii invoke the ALTER VIEW statement in order to populate with data prior to performing the various actions?

Here's an example:

MySQL VIEW:

```
DELIMITER $$
ALTER ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `my_db`.`vw_last30daysorders` AS 
SELECT
  `d`.`OrderID` AS `OrderID`,
  COUNT(`d`.`PropertyID`) AS `cntprops`,
  `m`.`RequestID`   AS `RequestID`
FROM (`my_db`.`orders_d` `d`
   JOIN `my_db`.`orders_m` `m`)
WHERE ((`d`.`OrderID` = `m`.`OrderID`)
       AND (`m`.`OrderDate` BETWEEN(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
            AND CURDATE()))
GROUP BY `d`.`OrderID`$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And the Yii Model class:

```
class VWLast30DaysOrders extends CActiveRecord
{
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'vw_last30daysorders';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('requestid', 'required'),
            array('requestid', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('totreqs', 'length', 'max'=>21),
            array('totreqsprops', 'length', 'max'=>42),
            array('requestid, totreqs, totreqsprops', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    public function relations()
    {
        return array();
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'requestid' => 'Requestid',
            'totreqs' => 'Totreqs',
            'totreqsprops' => 'Totreqsprops',
        );
    }
    public function search()
    {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->compare('requestid',$this->requestid);
        $criteria->compare('totreqs',$this->totreqs,true);
        $criteria->compare('totreqsprops',$this->totreqsprops,true);
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array('criteria'=>$criteria));
    }
}
```

I've checked the DB for triggers that could possibly be adding data to the view but failed to find any.

Comment: I'm asking how the Yii model class deals with the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii doesn't invoke an alter view statement.

Using views in Yii is a shortcut to using complex model relations.  Your view model is effectively read-only.

When you instantiate the model class Yii will query the database with a 'SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM ....' statement which returns the column information which then populates the ActiveQuery Object.

You use your VWLast30DaysOrders model in Yii much like any other data model except that it is read-only.

For Yii2, you therefore would use code such as:

```
$orders = VWLast30DaysOrders::find()->where(...)
```

Your model is a bit misleading though, as the rules() function does not match-up with the rest of the model nor with the view and should therefore be updated (if needed for validation) or cleared, if not.

Comment: So, if I understand, the VIEW gets re-populated with data via it's own definition each time the model class is instantiated?

Comment: the model view gets repopulated every time you search it.  The data model is the code version of the SQL view, so just sits there until you tell it to do something like findAll().  The SQL view is just a "pre-compiled" select statement, so doesn't contain data, just gets it from the database when you ask for it.